# Aggregate a column of dict into a list of dict with pivot_table - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

### I have a dataframe input like this :

```
data = {'annee': [2015, 2015],
        'medaille': ['Argent', 'Bronze'],
        'categorie': ['Punchs', 'Punchs'],
        'raisonSociale': ['Héritiers H Clément', 'Héritiers H Clément'],
        'Marque': ['Clément', 'Clément'],
        'Medaille_Rhum': [{'annee': 2015,
                           'medaille': 'Argent',
                           'produit': np.nan,
                           'Rhum_Name': 'PUNCH CAFE CLEMENT',
                           'Age': np.nan,
                           'labels': np.nan},
                          {'annee': 2015,
                           'medaille': 'Bronze',
                           'produit': np.nan,
                           'Rhum_Name': 'PUNCH PINA COLADA CLEMENT',
                           'Age': np.nan,
                           'labels': np.nan}],
        'Or': [0, 0],
        'Argent': [1, 0],
        'Bronze': [0, 1],
        'Score': [2, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Yes it's a dataframe of caribbean's rhums**

I want to use `pivot_table()` to have 'annee' (e.g. year) in columns with score values. I achieve it, but I also want to have the 'Rhum_Name' column aggregate in a list of dict.

### I tried the following code :

```
def ListDict(df):
    listDict = []
    listDict.extend(df)
    return listDict


df_ranking = df_ranking.pivot_table(index=['raisonSociale', 'Marque', 'categorie'],
                              columns =['annee', 'Medaille_Rhum'],
                              values = 'Score',
                              fill_value = '',
                              aggfunc = {'annee': sum, 'Medaille_Rhum': ListDict},
                              margins = True, 
                              margins_name = 'Total')
```

I get this error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. I asume it's because, `pivot_table` wants to iterate directly over the dict, but I can't picture how to make it work.

Thanks in advance guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Convert the dict into a dataframe
- Convert `'Medaille_Rhum'`, which is a column of `dicts`, into a dataframe and join it back to `df`.
- Don't try to reshape `Medaille_Rhum` in the `pivot_table`

### form the dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the dict in medaille_Rhum to a dataframe and join it back to df
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Medaille_Rhum').values.tolist())['Rhum_Name'])

# display(df)
   annee medaille categorie        raisonSociale   Marque  Or  Argent  Bronze  Score                  Rhum_Name
0   2015   Argent    Punchs  Héritiers H Clément  Clément   0       1       0      2         PUNCH CAFE CLEMENT
1   2015   Bronze    Punchs  Héritiers H Clément  Clément   0       0       1      1  PUNCH PINA COLADA CLEMENT
```

### create list of Medaille_Rhum

```py
medaille_rhum = [v for v in data['Medaille_Rhum']]

# print(medaille_rhum)
[{'annee': 2015,
  'medaille': 'Argent',
  'produit': nan,
  'Rhum_Name': 'PUNCH CAFE CLEMENT',
  'Age': nan,
  'labels': nan},
 {'annee': 2015,
  'medaille': 'Bronze',
  'produit': nan,
  'Rhum_Name': 'PUNCH PINA COLADA CLEMENT',
  'Age': nan,
  'labels': nan}]
```